# Organize Summary of String?

Tags: java, string, format, summary

I'm new to java and would be delighted if somebody here can point me in the right direction in getting some information.

I am trying to create a Java program that would allow me to enter a string in a certain format (for instance a tweet with the `@` and `hashtags`) and produce a summary of all the information i input and put them in categories (going back to the tweet example, things like `name`, `tweet text`, `hashtag`, etc)

as i've said before, i'm new at this so i do not even know the term of what i'm looking for and what to google. Anything that can help me will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will probably need to learn Regular expression: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: An example of what you are trying to achieve will help :)

Comment: You can read the input as a string and then parse it with regular expression, when you say that there is a pattern

Answer (score 3):

It seems you need to learn regular expression in Java
Here is an *official* tutorial from Oracle:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

This is also an interesting, easy to follow, article that teaches you the basics

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: +1. Very good references. To the OP: What you are wanting to do is to "parse" a `String`. Searching for this term may help you on your way. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called [Lexical Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), it is the process of tokenizing input according to a certain set of rules

> lexical analysis is the process of converting a sequence of characters into a sequence of tokens. A program or function which performs lexical analysis is called a lexical analyzer, lexer, or scanner. A lexer often exists as a single function which is called by a parser or another function.

However, for what you would like to do, using a `lexer` may be overdoing it (given the information you want to retrieve)

A few simple [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) may do the job for you, for example getting a hashtag with text (assuming hashtags are only `a-z`)

```
String rexex = "#[a-z]+";
```